# How to use tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage to evaluate a model which is trained without exponential decay in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

First of all, maybe I have understood the exponential decay and what tf. train. exponentialMovingAverage does not yet do completely. Maybe:) As far as I have understood so far, a copy is made for each variable with which different calculations can be carried out in order to obtain either a better training or evaluation result. If someone knows a clear explanation, I would be very happy about it (in English or German).

Now to my problem, I'm training a CNN using `tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage` (if more code is needed I'll add it later, please comment).

```
...
variable_averages =
tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(get_movining_average_decay(), global_step)

variables_averages_op = 
variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())
...
```

Afterwards I evaluate the model using `tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage`, which works fine.

```
...
variable_averages = 
tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(get_movining_average_decay())
# This may be the problem, 
# if no shadow variables have been created during the training, 
# no variables can be restored.
variables_to_restore = variable_averages.variables_to_restore()
saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
...
```

But if I train the CNN without `tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage` I cannot evaluate the model using `tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage`. Very likely this line would have to be changed, but I wouldn't know what by.

```
variables_to_restore = variable_averages.variables_to_restore()
```

How to customize the this code or is that not possible in TensorFlow or have I still not understood exponential decay enough and in general it is not possible?